# Is there an alternative for Autorun.inf for a CD or DVD in Windows 7/8/8.1/10? I can't make it work in Win10

Tags: autorun

Most of what I have found on this topic is really for **Autorun.inf** files for USB sticks.

Many folks say that feature was dropped for USB sticks when Win7 and later versions of Windows came along but it was kept for CDs and DVDs.

I have used the standard Autorun.inf code that I could find in several places on the Internet, but it does not work for the CDs that I have burned.

I can open a disk and look at the files on the disk and click on my **.exe** file and it launches and runs fine.

My **Autorun.inf** file just will not execute it when the CD is first loaded and run on my computer which is running Win10.

Is anyone still successful with running **Autorun.inf** files on CDs or DVDs on computers with Windows 7/8/8.1/10?

If so, how is the Autorun.inf file configured?

All I want to do is launch a **.exe** file that is in the root directory of the CD or DVD.

Is it required to have the line of code to specify where the icon can be found?

I am including that code but I wonder if it is required as well.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to a configuration on the target machine that you cannot control, such as antivirus software or autorun default settings in Windows.

Comment: maybe ask on superuser...